# VS 2017 Checkin & JIRA Stories

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, jira

My company is evaluating JIRA as TFS scrum seems lacking. My question is how can we have a check-in policy, to include a JIRA story as a for check in?

We current have a policy to make sure a comment is given & the code builds. We are looking to add an "work item" policy. This would require the change-set tied to a particular ticket/story. But we need this "work item" to pull from JIRA.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you mean by "gated check in"? Is this a source code versioning question or is it about something else?

Comment: hey @ZeddZull - i've updated & hopefully clarified it a bit more. Gated Check-in perhaps was the wrong term. "Check-In Policy" is what I think is a more common term. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-check-policies

Comment: I don't have any experience with TFS, but if that is what you are using for version control, you might want to look at TFS4JIRA plugin at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira/cloud/overview which provides integration between the two systems. In general, you can configure Jira to enforce pretty much any policy you want.

Comment: @ZeddZull - i'm trying to get that one to work now... isn't going well. Thank you thou for the suggestion. I am going to keep plugging away!